# Strength of DES encryption if encrypted string is known?

Tags: security, encryption

I'm using DES to encrypt some strings. Using this example:

http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/PassKey.html

Let's say an attacker finds out what one of my encrypted string's decrypted value is. For example, they somehow find out that the word I was encrypting is "dog". Now they have both the encrypted and decrypted values. Is it then trivial to figure out how to decrypt all the rest of my data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you are asking is "does DES have any known vulnerabilities to [known plaintext attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack)?". The answer is, as things stand, no (to the best of my knowledge), although such attacks have been published against reduced strength versions.

Since the key length of DES is effectively only 56 bits, it is not really strong enough for current use if you really want security - this is coming well within the bounds of brute force attacks nowadays, particularly if you only have a single block encrypted (as in your example of "dog").

Comment: What do you mean,"particularly if you only have a single block encrypted"? Encrypting more plaintext certainly will not make it more secure.